# Dell LCD monitor has no power

Tags: display

My Dell LCD monitor is. not working, there is no power at all. Warranty is gone I think. (Plus it stopped working after it fell from table.)

Is there a way I can narrow it down to whether the issue is with the power button? I have opened it up, so I do have access to the button circuit board.

I have already tried things like removing the power cord, changing power outlet etc.

Comment: I took a good look at the prongs, and they SEEMED okay (meaning not broken). Should I looking at other things too?

Comment: Are you using a voltmeter?  What kind of damage was sustained after it fell off the table?

Comment: I'd be looking first at the connections where the power socket connects to the supply if it the cable was pulled tight when it fell.

Comment: @sawdust, when I said "no power", I meant no light at all around the power button. I do have access to multimeter though. Where should I be looking?

Comment: If it's unplugged, then you could check for continuity with the multimeter from the prongs into the display.  If you're more experienced, then check for voltages.  Power buttons (versus power switch) are usually low voltage logic inputs in a logic circuit, and do not directly control the AC power.